# CSS: How to get a button to always be to the left of another button that's in a corner?

Tags: html, css

```
---------------------------------------------
|   text                                    |
|   text                                    |
|   text                                    |
|   text                                    |
|   text                                    |
|   text                   -------  ------- |
|   textttttttttttttt     |Button1||Button2||
|                          -------  ------- |
---------------------------------------------
```

So I want Button1 to always be to the left of Button2, and Button2 to always be on the bottom right of the div. How can I do that? By the way, currently, my code has the two buttons part of the "texttttttttttttt" line. I didn't make separate div/spans for the text and buttons.

Comment: "I didn't make separate div/spans for the text and buttons." Do it and add style like "float: right".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a little of both approaches needs to be done here.

First in order to get the buttons to layout in the corner with text wrap you will have to wrap them in a div

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="button-left">Text</button>
    <button class="button-left">Text</button>
</div>
```

and your css

```
.buttons {
    position:absolute; 
    right:5px; 
    bottom:5px;
    width: 100px;
}

.button-left {
    float:left;
    width:45px;
    margin: 0 2px
}

.button-right {
    float:right;
    width:45px;
    margin:0 2px;
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this..?

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Utm7z/).

I just did the obvious, and floated the elements.

```
.paragraph {
    float:left;
}
.buttons {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use absolute positioning

If you style the container to be positioned relatively, then you may position the child elements absolutely if necessary. Giving you more control over their location relative to the container. This is often used to create a div that expands to match the height of the container it's in; e.g., `.right-column-full { position:absolute; top:10px; bottom:10px; right:5px; }`

---

## Why use absolute positioning?

The major pitfall in Josh C's solution, is if you add additional text or change the height of the container div (among other changes), your buttons will remain where they are unless you also adjust their margin-top properties.

For perhaps a simpler and more easily manageable solution, you can do something like the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="infoblock-container">
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</p>
    <input type="button" class="button-one" value="Button-One">
    <input type="button" class="button-two" value="Button-Two">
</div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
.infoblock-container {position:relative;}
.button-one {position:absolute; right:5px; bottom:5px; width:80px; margin-right:84px;}
.button-two {position:absolute; right:5px; bottom:5px; width:80px;}
```

---

**Demo**

- [**JsFiddle demo (Absolute positioning)**](http://jsfiddle.net/mUeRR/1/)

Unlike Josh C's solution, this will always keep the buttons at the bottom right corner and will always have a 5px (or whatever you specify) distance from the edge. By specifying the width and margin, we easily give the right-most button enough room plus 4px.

---